# Chameleon template global variables

Tags: python, pyramid, chameleon, template-metal

I am using Pyramid 1.3 and their templates written in Chameleon.
As different pages or templates might need a global stylesheet change per page, I would like to be able to redefine classes of the body tag on the page (of course, I would prefer to do this from the templates).

```
<body class="${global_variable_or_something_else}"></body>
```

What I have tried:

- Using tal:define="global body_class" from the submacros. Doesn't work.
- I have tried to use `<metal:div metal:define-slot="vars">...variable definition...</metal:div>` and `<metal:div metal:fill-slot="vars">...redefinition...</metal:div>`, and redefining the variables in the submacros. It does work, but what if I have several variable definitions in the parent template and I need to redefine only one?

Is there a good way of doing this better with METAL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Globals in page templates, like globals in Python, can be overridden. So you do the following instead:

```xml
<rootelement metal:define-macro="macroname"
             tal:define="global var1 value1; global var2 value2">
    <metal:overrides define-slot="overrides"></metal:overrides>
    <!-- some template code using var1 and var2 -->
</rootelement>
```

Then use a `metal:fill-slot` to provide overrides; you can override as few or as many of the variables as you want:

```xml
<rootelement metal:use-macro="macroname">
    <metal:overrides fill-slot="overrides"><tal:defines define="global var1 differentvalue" /></metal:overrides>
</rootelement>
```

Comment: What version of Chameleon did you use to test this solution?

Comment: @AndreyCizov: none; I am making assumptions here based on (a lot of) experience with TAL (zope page templates). It could be that Chameleon's implementation has optimized this codepath away.